# Make children of LazyVerticalGrid increase their spanSize to accomodate their intrinsic max width

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I'm trying to use `LazyVerticalGrid` to display some Layouts containing text. I'd like these items with an intrinsic max width greater than one column's width to have a span of 2 etc. In this manner text is more likely to be single-line, and will wrap only when space has run out.

I'm looking for some way to access the intrinsic max width inside `LazyVerticalGrid#spans` but not sure if that's the correct approach.

I'm also looking at `layout()` and `subcompose()` functions but not sure if I could even use the width to set the spans at that point.

`FlowRow` doesn't have a notion of columns so is difficult to use as I'd like each column to line up. i.e. views should have some width which is a multiple of col width (+ spacing between columns)

The effect I'm after is something like this:

[image]

If the intrinsicWidthMax is large enough then the item will consume additional spans.